# Run aggregation on multiple fields in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am working on a used cars marketplace website similar to https://www.kijijiautos.ca.
I want to make an aggregation on my dataset, to get the number of cars with for eg "Ford" and in the same aggregation I want to get the total number of used cars, new cars and other specifications

I tried the following:

```
GET auto/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "stats": {
      "multi_terms": {
        "terms": [{"field": "Make"}, {"field": "Type"}]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got the following result

```
{
  "took" : 149,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "stats" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 14378,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : [
            "BMW",
            "Used"
          ],
          "key_as_string" : "BMW|Used",
          "doc_count" : 2826
        },
        {
          "key" : [
            "Volkswagen",
            "Used"
          ],
          "key_as_string" : "Volkswagen|Used",
          "doc_count" : 2592
        },
        {
          "key" : [
            "Audi",
            "Used"
          ],
          "key_as_string" : "Audi|Used",
          "doc_count" : 2310
        },
        {
          "key" : [
            "Opel",
            "Used"
          ],
          "key_as_string" : "Opel|Used",
          "doc_count" : 1494
        },
        {
          "key" : [
            "Ford",
            "Used"
          ],
          "key_as_string" : "Ford|Used",
          "doc_count" : 1485
        },
        {
          "key" : [
            "Renault",
            "Used"
          ],
          "key_as_string" : "Renault|Used",
          "doc_count" : 1303
        },
        {
          "key" : [
            "Peugeot",
            "Used"
          ],
          "key_as_string" : "Peugeot|Used",
          "doc_count" : 1196
        },
        {
          "key" : [
            "Fiat",
            "Used"
          ],
          "key_as_string" : "Fiat|Used",
          "doc_count" : 1149
        },
        {
          "key" : [
            "Skoda",
            "Used"
          ],
          "key_as_string" : "Skoda|Used",
          "doc_count" : 668
        },
        {
          "key" : [
            "SEAT",
            "Used"
          ],
          "key_as_string" : "SEAT|Used",
          "doc_count" : 629
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but that's not what I am expecting
what I expect is the following :

```
{
  // first bucket
  [
    {
      "doc_count" : 123,
      "key" : "BMW"
    }
    // other makes here
  ]
  // second bucket
  [
    {
      "doc_count" : 2500,
      "key" : "Used"
    },
    {
      "doc_count" : 500,
      "key" : "New"
    }
  ]
}
```

If this is possible in elasticsearch then please help me write this query

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem, and I would like to leave it here for ref. ( found the solution [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/combining-two-aggregations/211624) )

the idea is to specify multiple aggregations inside the aggs object that's all

```
GET auto/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {

    // aggregate on types
    "types": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Type",
        "size": 10
      }
    },

    // aggregate on makes
    "makes": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Make",
        "size": 10
      }
    },

    // aggregate on body types
    "body type": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Body Type",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the result was as expected

```
{
  "took" : 10,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "types" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Used",
          "doc_count" : 22414
        },
        {
          "key" : "New",
          "doc_count" : 3021
        },
        {
          "key" : "Pre-registered",
          "doc_count" : 2071
        },
        {
          "key" : "Demonstration",
          "doc_count" : 1427
        },
        {
          "key" : "Employee's car",
          "doc_count" : 900
        },
        {
          "key" : "Antique / Classic",
          "doc_count" : 195
        },
        {
          "key" : "Automatic",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "Metallic",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "makes" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 9814,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Volkswagen",
          "doc_count" : 3295
        },
        {
          "key" : "BMW",
          "doc_count" : 3212
        },
        {
          "key" : "Audi",
          "doc_count" : 2768
        },
        {
          "key" : "Ford",
          "doc_count" : 2109
        },
        {
          "key" : "Opel",
          "doc_count" : 1840
        },
        {
          "key" : "Fiat",
          "doc_count" : 1692
        },
        {
          "key" : "Renault",
          "doc_count" : 1691
        },
        {
          "key" : "Peugeot",
          "doc_count" : 1458
        },
        {
          "key" : "Skoda",
          "doc_count" : 1193
        },
        {
          "key" : "SEAT",
          "doc_count" : 958
        }
      ]
    },
    "body type" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Sedans",
          "doc_count" : 8410
        },
        {
          "key" : "Off-Road/Pick-up",
          "doc_count" : 6498
        },
        {
          "key" : "Station wagon",
          "doc_count" : 4894
        },
        {
          "key" : "Compact",
          "doc_count" : 3516
        },
        {
          "key" : "Van",
          "doc_count" : 1844
        },
        {
          "key" : "Transporter",
          "doc_count" : 1539
        },
        {
          "key" : "Coupe",
          "doc_count" : 1144
        },
        {
          "key" : "Convertible",
          "doc_count" : 1104
        },
        {
          "key" : "Other",
          "doc_count" : 654
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```